# javascript in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

Is it possible somehow to use javascript code inside C++? For example I have some js library and want to use some it's methods in my C++ project (I know about emscripten but it looks like I have to build C++ code with `emcc`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible that you can run the javascript in your c++ code but you need a javascript engine like **[V8](https://v8.dev/)** Maybe this will help you a lot.

Comment: You could add explaining, how _emscripten_ is a different thing, sort of opposite to what is asked (because it is mentioned in the question and even tagged there).